# Эффект Aero Glass в windows 10 версии 1709

Tags: c#, uwp, aeroglass

В Windows 10 версии 1709 окно calc.exe сделали с эффектом Aero Glass (как в Windows 7). [image: эффект aero glass]
Причем, эффект проявляется только если окно активно, если неактивно, то эффект плавно исчезает.
В связи с этим вопрос: можно ли реализовать подобное в Visual Studio на UWP + C#?

Answer (score 4):

Называется это - `Fluent Design`. Можно это реализовать в UWP с помощью [`Navigation view`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview), например. Одна беда: нужно что-бы на исполняемой машине была установлена Windows 10 с Fall Creators Update. (версия 16299, API v5)

Answer (score 2):

Точнее это называется AcrylicBrush и применяется к фону элемента. Но таки да, доступно из коробки только в FCU.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно. Для этого вам нужно скачать свежее SDK, или обновить Visual Studio до последней версии. О том, как использовать акриловые кисти, более подробно описано в [официальной документации Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic)